# Как проверить e-mail c#?

Tags: c#

Можно ли отправить e-mail серверу проверочный запрос, что б подтвердить существование ящика?  (Без авторизации). Поддерживают ли mail-сервера такую валидацию? Или максимум что можно проверить - это существование домена, и соответствие регулярке (форме имя@домен)?
Поддерживет ли pop3 или smtp протоколы анонимную валидацию ящика?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Можно проверить на уровне SMTP протола:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/565504/how-to-check-if-an-email-address-exists-without-sending-an-email

(под C# https://github.com/adoconnection/EmailValidator.NET)

Однако, это зависит от настроек почтового сервера, и некоторые эти опции отключают, чтобы не идентифицировать своих пользователей. 
Поэтому, имхо, не стоит этого делать.

Есть проверенный практикой метод подтвержения емейл: отправка на почту письма с ссылкой подтверждения, после которого юзер в полную меру может использовать сайт. Самый простой и явный способ.

Comment: Нашёл http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/smtp.php тут есть команда VRFY, её SMTP поддерживет? Нужно самому писать отправку что б учесть ответ от VRFY при отправке письма?

Comment: да, это есть часть протокола STMP, но включен ли надо проверять на целевом сервере. Можно писать самому, можно использовать готовые решения, по ссылке выше есть для C#.

Comment: Что именно вы используете на своём сайте для валидации mail? Т.е. есть ли смысл не пропускать юзера с "плохим" майлом провереным конкретным способом, или методы эти не всегда дают хороший результат?

Comment: вообще я не вижу смысла в чем-то ограничивать действия юзера. 
ну вбил он левый адрес и использует его. 
единственное, что он не сможет сделать - это восстановить пароль. 
если вам нужно рассылать письма на почту, то у большинства email delivery sender service есть трекинг 
прочтения письма. И вы сможете просмотреть что из 1000 писем, прочитали только 600 (и посмотреть кто это). 
некоторые даже имеют фичу отписывать автоматом, если письма не читают.
как-то так.

Comment: по опыту где нет необходимости в идентификации пользователя вообще подтверждение не нужно.
нужно там где есть к примеру комментарии, то ссылка с письмом на почту. 
если нужно более, то привязка к телефону.